Copy-Paste problem with VSCode on linux : entire file content being re-copied
I stumble on a strange problem with my vscode (which apparently has already occurred to someone https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/spgk8t/ctrl_v_acts_weird/).
When I paste some text on vscode, the text is copied and just after the entire content of the file is also copied.
The user who reported the problem did not post any solution or follow-up on the problem. Therefore I post it here, to leave a record if someone finds the solution.
